# accessing elements in json through javascript

Tags: javascript, json, api, parsing, element

I'm trying to parse a local json through a local network. However, It gives me this error ( Unexpected token } in JSON at position 241) if I tried to parse it and according to my research in stackoverflow it is already an object. you will see that I tried to turn it to string and parse it again but that didn't help.
so right now I'm trying to access the JSON object but it either gives me an error or the output is undefined.
keeping in mind that when I console.log(body), it actually shows me the JSON information.
when I try to console.log(body[2]) it would give me a letter or a bracket as if I'm returning from a string not an element from an object.

what I want is to be able to extract a piece of certain information and be able to store it or send it to the client.
here is my code:

```
var app = express();
app.use(express.static('.'));
app.listen(3000);

var request = require('request');

app.get("/car", function(req, res) {
var url = "http://localhost:3000/car.json";
request.get(url, function(error, response, body) {
    var return_val = [];
    //console.log(test); do not work
    //console.log(body.cars.response[0]); do not work
    var info = JSON.stringify(body); //will turn it to string
    console.log(info);
    var test = JSON.parse(info);
    console.log(test);  //will see the JSON in its original form
    console.log(test[1]); will show me a letter or bracket 
    //console.log(test.cars); //do not work
    res.send();
    res.end();
});
});

here is my JSON, car.json is the file name.
{
  "cars": [
    {
      "car_title": "bmw",
      "rating": 8.6,
      "brand": "bmw",
      "release_date": ["2019/08","2009/10"],
    },
    {
      "car_title": "fiat",
      "rating": 9.2,
      "brand": "fiat",
      "release_date": ["2008/07","2006/12"],
    }
]
}
```

Comment: If the `body` is json, then you can use `console.log(body.cars[0].car_title);`.

Comment: I tried this and it gave me this error ' Cannot read property '0' of undefined'

Comment: wrong line `var test = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(info));` change to  `var test = JSON.parse(info);` ?

Comment: I tried the double parsing instead of the standard one (which also didn't work) as someone recommends it, however, it didn't work. now I have removed it from the code so it won't confuse anyone.

Comment: It would be useful if you could show us exactly what your `car.json` file contains. It certainly cannot start with `car =`, since the `=` will trigger an error far earlier than character position 241. Looking at that file at character position 241 will almost certainly help you diagnose your problem, but I can't do that for you since I can't see your file.

Comment: car is the file name, ill adjust it to make it clearer. the content of the file is included at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

If your JSON is in any way related to the text you pasted into your question which claims to be your JSON, then the problem is quite clear. (That text cannot actually be the contents of `car.json`, because `car =` is not the start of a valid JSON file of any type.

I believe what the JSON parser is trying to tell you is that the commas at the end of each car object are not valid. JSON doesn't allow trailing commas in objects or arrays, nor does it allow empty fields. So a comma cannot be followed by a `}`; it must be followed by a valid datum. After the JSON processor sees a comma, it doesn't expect a `}`. So it complains.

So remove the commas from the ends of lines:

```json
      "release_date": ["2019/08","2009/10"],

      "release_date": ["2008/07","2006/12"],
```

Comment: That actually worked! the file was provided to me so I assumed it was flawless. once I removed the coma the parsing worked! Thank you so much.